# Pause update of progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

*(Sorry for the not-so-good-title, I'm not sure how my problem can be solved, thus what is the question I need to ask :)*

## Context

I use a progress bar to inform the user of the progress of a task. The task is in fact done in two steps, each of them taking approximately half of the total time to be performed. I only know the length of the second task just before starting it (because it depends on the results of the previous task), so I can't know the maximum progress at the very beginning. That is why I change the maximum progress of my progress bar before the second task.

This is basically how I do it:

```
// 1st step
progressBar.Maximum = step1Objects.Count * 2; // "2" because the step will take 
                                              // half of the total process
progressBar.Value = 0;
foreach (SomeObject step1Object in step1Objects) {
    // Build step2Objects
    progressBar.Value = ++progress;
}
// At this moment, the progress bar is half filled

// 2nd step
progressBar.Maximum = step2Objects.Count * 2;
progressBar.Value = step2Objects.Count;
// When we start this step, the progress bar is already half filled
foreach (SomeObject step2Object in step2Objects) {
    // Do something
    progressBar.Value = ++progress;
}
// At this moment, the progress bar is totally filled
```

## Problem

When I get to this line:

```
progressBar.Maximum = step2Objects.Count * 2;
```

... the progress bar is for a short instant not half filled anymore because `step1Objects.Count` is very little compared to `step2Objects.Count`. So the progress bar does something like that (that's what the user sees):

```
>          |
=>         |
==>        |
===>       |
====>      |
=====>     |  End of step 1
=>         |  progressBar.Maximum = step2Objects.Count * 2;
=====>     |  progressBar.Value = step2Objects.Count;
======>    |
=======>   |
========>  |
=========> |
==========>|
```

## Question

How can I avoid this "glitch"?

I think that the thing to do is stop the refresh of the progress bar between the two steps. I was thinking at something like [BeginUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.beginupdate.aspx)/[EndUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.endupdate.aspx), but it doesn't seem to exist for progress bars...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write that both tasks are approximately half of the total time to be performed.

```
progressBar.Maximum = 100;

var stepPercentage = 50 / step1Objects.Count;
foreach(SomeObject step1Object in step1Objects)
{
    progressBar.Progress += stepPercentage;
}

progressBar.Progress = 50;
stepPercentage = 50 / step2Objects.Count;
foreach(SomeObject step2Object in step2Objects)
{
    progressBar.Progress += (stepPercentage + 50);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set Max of progressBar to step1Objects.Count * step2Objects.Count * 2

```
progressBar.Maximum = step1Objects.Count * step2Objects.Count * 2;
```

Then in your loop, try:

```
progressBar.Value = 0;
//phase 1
foreach (SomeObject step1Object in step1Objects) {
    // Build step2Objects
    progress = progress + step2Objects.Count;
    progressBar.Value = progress;
}

//phase 2
foreach (SomeObject step2Object in step2Objects) {
    // Do something
    progress = progress + step1Objects.Count;
    progressBar.Value = progress;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a standard value say 100 or 200. Now divide by two. Half for step one and half for step two. Now you know how many items you have for step one so divide 50% by that many to get the amount for each object completion in step one. This means that once step one has finished 50% of your progress bar is full. Now the next 50% is divided by the amount of step 2 objects you have and you add x amount for each object to the 50% you have already filled.